# Combining excel files with different sheets

Tags: excel, pandas, glob

i have a huge problem. I have multiple excel files with same sheet names
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xONQw.png)
I need to combine only sheets, not to create only one huge for examplae. Sheet Summer with Summer, Winter with Winter, not creating one sheet with all walues

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import xlrd
location = ("direction\*.xlsx")
excles_files = glob.glob(location)
 How can i even have the  sheet names to try
Pd.combine_sheet
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(location, on_demand=True)
print(xls.sheet_names())
```

This is not working
Thank you

Comment: u can mention sheetname while reading excels... pd.read_excel('path/filename.xlsx', sheet_name="Summer") & for appending can try with pd.append([df1,df2],axis=1)

Comment: This will not working, if will be a lot of files with all this sheets

Comment: Did you try Power Query for this task?

Comment: no, never used it